# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04: Everytime software is updated PC reboots and Linux gets broken

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, nvidia, gnome

so I am a new user to Linux. I installed Ubuntu Gnome and everytime I try to upgrade software using the terminal or using software updates, the computers shuts down and restarts and linux gets inaccessible. I already tried to use noveau.modeset=0 in linux kernel (i had some problems with the nvidia drivers), but no solution was found.

I removed the install formated the PC with windows intaller. Although this has not fixed the boot BIOS menu (GURB maintained), it allowed me to re-install the Ubuntu Gnome. The problem is that using software update brings the same problem. I removed and reinstalled again and again and seems to be no solution.
Sometimes when installing ubuntu reboots and fails installing gnu grub and i have to do it again until it gets it right. Can someone please help me?

I was really enjoying this distro, if you could help me i would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the correct nvidia drivers from the official package management system instead of using the downloaded compiled version or install dkms and recompile the nvidia drivers so that you won't have this problem after every update.

For now, you should be able to boot up using one of the older kernels. Select advanced options from the grub menu and then select one of the older kernels and do not select the newest kernel.

---

Next, search for **software sources** or open the **ubuntu-software-center**, select **edit** and then select **software sources**.

Then, select the **additional drivers** tab and then select the recommended nvidia proprietary driver that is marked "tested". Apply your selection and when you are done, reboot.

---

Alternatively, if you insist on using the downloaded version of the nvidia driver, install dkms so that you won't break your system after an update:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

[Click here for more info.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can0t acess old kernels, because i used windows repair to remove them from efi. I installed the drivers from windows. But the isntallation rebooted again during grub 2 installation

Comment: I finally got it! Thanks for your help cl-netbox. The USB ISO was probably corrupted so i built it using another iso (this was not at the first neither the second attempt).

When i finally got to Try withough intalling gnome (without editing the kernel to nouveau.modeset=0 and not leading to nouveau errors), i connected to internet and did on terminal:

sudo get-apt update


then I went to additional drivers and selected Nvidia recomended, rebooted and installed perfectly.

Comment: Good one!  +1  **;-)** I've been replace by 2 nVidia experts now...  I'll know who to call when I see another nVidia problem!  **:D**